# Excel VBA range value sometimes fails a comparison check

Tags: excel, vba

**Situation**

On a worksheet I have a `named range` called `total_Dist` (which will be a value between 0 and 1, formatted as a percentage).

In `VBA` I am checking to see if this value `=1` using an `IF` statement. Here is the entire code, and I've highlighted the `IF` statement by the comment `****Issue occurs here***`. The code is called by the user pressing a button on a worksheet.

```
Sub distribution_Next()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim i As Integer

    Set tbl = Range("tbl_Activity").ListObject

    '****Issue occurs here***
    If Range("total_Dist").Value <> 1 Then   'the time allocation does not equal 100%
        MsgBox "Please ensure the total time allocated adds up to 100%"
        GoTo clean
    Else
        Debug.Print "else"
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With tbl
        For i = 1 To .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            'enable/visible each worksheet that has a time allocation
            If .ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value > 0 Then
                Worksheets(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value).Visible = True
            Else
                Worksheets(.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value).Visible = False
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Sheets("Finish").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Distribution of Time").Activate     'included this line to stop 'nextPage' going to incorrect sheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    nextPage

clean:
    'clean up
    Set tbl = Nothing

End Sub
```

**The Issue**

Sometimes, even when the `range = 1` the code still enters the `IF` statement, as shown in the screenshot:

[image: If statement failing]

You can see from the tiptext, and the 'Watches' window that the value `=1`, yet it has still entered the `IF` statement.

This doesn't happen every time, but I can't see a pattern or work out why it would fail like this.

**Notes**

I have tried it without the `.value`, and with `.value2`.

I am using Excel 2013 on a Windows 7 machine.

**edit / update**

This screenshot shows that it sometimes passes the `IF` check:

[image: If statement pass]

Comment: Is "total_Dist" a static value or dynamic? If it's a dynamic value, then it might be possible that the value changed after the IF statement has been executed. Please clarify. Best Regards,

Comment: @AlexBell "total_Dist" does not change after the VBA module has started

Comment: Sorry, what is .value2 and .value?

Comment: @AlexBell All three of `Range("total_Dist")`, `Range("total_Dist").value` and `Range("total_Dist").value2` 'appear' to evaluate to 1

Comment: Could you please include the entire code snippet causing the problem? It's hard to make any analysis based on this rather limited input. Thanks and regards,

Comment: For simple testing purpose, comment off everything starting with the line (Application.ScreenUpdating = False) and down to (next page)  inclusive, and see how it works.

Comment: I'll give it a go once I can re-create the error (as sometimes it passes and I don't know why).

Comment: Please delete .value, in my test it works with 100% = 1 `If Range("total_Dist").Value <> 1 Then` **Update** -> see that you already tried this. Check my sample with Cells: `Sub test4()
i = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3))
If Cells(i, 3) <> 1 Then
j = 3
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub`

Comment: Tried it also with a named range and works also with 100% = 1

Comment: I would imagine it's a floating point issue - try: `If Round(Range("total_Dist").Value, 7) <> 1 Then` for instance

Comment: @Rory using `Round` has solved every instance, although I use `Round( ... , 0)`, is there a specific reason you used `7` as the number of decimals? If you add your solution as an answer I'll give it a tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it's a floating point issue so the actual value is not precisely 1. If so you can use:

```
If Round(Range("total_Dist").Value, 7) <> 1 Then
```

for instance. The 7 is an arbitrary number depending on the level of precision you need. I tend to use it as it is usually enough decimal places to rule out floating point errors but not introduce new rounding issues. (Remember that for a percentage value shown to 2DP, rounding the actual value to 4 DP could affect the result based on actual values rather than floating point issues.)